# Handling keyboard input in SDL2

Tags: c#, input, sdl2, keyboard, .net

I'm using SDL2 with [.NET bindings](https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS). Keyboard handling is encapsulated in static class, and keyboard handling code part looks like this:

```
// class members
private static int _numkeys;
private static IntPtr _keysBuffer;
private static byte[] _keysCurr = new byte[(int)SDL_Scancode.SDL_NUM_SCANCODES];
private static byte[] _keysPrev = new byte[(int)SDL_Scancode.SDL_NUM_SCANCODES];

// called once, to get buffer pointer
_keysBuffer = SDL_GetKeyboardState(out _numkeys);

// update keyboard state each frame
var tmp = _keysPrev;
_keysPrev = _keysCurr;
_keysCurr = tmp;
// copy new state
Marshal.Copy(_keysBuffer, _keysCurr, 0, _numkeys);
```

all is workig as expected mostly, however once in while one of the following behavior occurs:

1. Physical key is pressed, but no key press is detected. Keypress is detected after key repeat interval.
2. Physical key is pressed, but no key press is detected. Lasts for infinite amount of time.

For example, I press Right (`D`), the movement to right starts, shortly after I press Fire (`SPACE`), movement is stopped, no firing occurs, then after key repeat interval firing starts, but movement to Right is stopped despite key is also still pressed.

Unfortunatelly I have both 1) not discovered 100% reproducible pattern for the bug yet (seems like it happens on burst sequental presses), 2) have no ideas what is the cause.

For now I just want, a fresh view on my code (is it solid?) and maybe some ideas on what to check. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a typical issue from [matrix keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit). IOW, that's a hardware issue.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the tip. But I have a ghosting-free gaming keyboard, so it's unlikely the issue IMO. But i'll check it out to be sure.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the event system instead of manually handling the key state?

Comment: @Pharap thanks for the option, but I'm happy with my implementation, would not change it unless there is unfixable bug :)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin You didn't answer the question, is there a reason you can't use the event system? The event system is designed purposely to avoid this sort of issue, and there's no marshalling involved.

Comment: @Pharap didn't I? Well, the reason is -- I love things as they are now, simple and fast, I see no one reason to change. Honestly I have no idea about what event system you are talking now, and how it's different from my approach. Could you also be so kind to explain what "issues" my code have now?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin The event system allows you to handle `KeyDown` events and `KeyUp` events separately which in most cases makes more sense than trying to check the current state of the keys. As for the advantage, it involves less processing because you only handle events when they happen rather than continually polling the hardware state every frame. I can't assess what's wrong with your code without seeing the rest of it, all you've shown us is the part where you copy the keyboard state, you haven't shown how you're handling the keys.

Comment: @Pharap thank you for explanation. This is how KeyboardState works internally (by processing events), I see no reason to implement it manually. Hence there is no additional processing either (since you pump all windows events anyway). I guess I could eliminate `Marshal.Copy` this way, but I would prefer simplicity in this case, since I think it cost almost nothing in terms of overall performance.

Comment: @Quentin you were right in some sense, this was hardware problem, but malfunction, not ghosting. If you wish to collect rep you earned, please post your comment as answer.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin glad to help! but I doubt "your keyboard is busted, get a new one" is a useful answer for future devs ;)

Comment: @Quentin I think people with actual ghosting could come up to this thread too, so it could be useful actually, since symptoms are actually quite similar. I just could not imagine there is such thing as a broken keyboard, especially rather new and expensive, so I just didn't bother to check.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin do check your warranty! Maybe you got one from a bad series :)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin You don't implement it manually, SDL2 already has an event system which doesn't cost anything using [`SDL_PollEvent`](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php). I was asking because I wanted to establish if the event system was also creating the same behaviour, which would have indicated that the flaw was something low-level (i.e. your keyboard) and not with your code.

Comment: @Pharap by *manually* I meant building that `switch-case` then polling events. As a wrote earlier, keyboard state is an equivalent to using `SDL_PollEvent` since it is updated internally by this call.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin They aren't equivalent. Keyboard state gives which keys are currently pressed, the keydown event activates when the state changes from released to pressed and the keyup event activates when the state changes from pressed to released. They are related, but not equivalent. (Also your current method is almost certainly marshalling 512 bytes every frame, and [`SDL_GetKeyboardState` does not internally call `SDL_PollEvent`](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/f9c06200b07f1eeac8ac59ec967ca50afe1cac55/src/events/SDL_keyboard.c#L822).)

Comment: @Pharap there is no such magic thing as 'keyboard state'. The **only** way to get keyboard state in windows is by processing events. Also it's the other way around `SDL_PollEvent` is updating 'keyboard state' buffer. If you want source code proof look at `SDL2-2.0.5\src\video\windows\SDL_windowsevents.c ` file. As for marshalling part, you not reading me carefully, see above: "I guess I could eliminate Marshal.Copy this way (meaning: *your* way), but I would prefer simplicity in this case, since I think it cost almost nothing in terms of overall performance."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surprisingly it actually turned out that [Quentin](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140937/handling-keyboard-input-in-sdl2?noredirect=1#comment249839_140937) was right is some sense. It was not keyboard ghosting however, but pure keyboard malfunction. It just happened that it really not reporting some keys pressed then they are. And it was incosistent as the "bug" was.

I used [Keyboard Ghosting Demonstration](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/KeyboardGhostingDemo.mspx) page and [Keyboard Ghosting & Rollover Test](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Info/Keyboard-Ghosting---Rollover-Test.shtml) windows app for the test.

The costly piece of garbage was replaced by my old good membrane keyboard and the "bug" is gone now.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a hardware issue as stated by @Quentin.

Anyways, you could write a workaround tracking the KEYDOWN and KEYUP events instead of trying to fetch the keyboard state, i'm not pretty sure how it works in C#, i've never worked with SDL2 in that language, but here's an example of how do I [manage it in C++](https://github.com/solarHunter/solarHunter/blob/master/src/entities/player.cpp#L18), i suppose it's pretty similar.

Instead of doing that, what you would need is an array of unsigned char, writting 1 into the key code index when pressed and 0 when released.

After that you will have the state of the keyboard with no hardware state dependency

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's exactly how SDL's keyboard state works internally! It simplifies keyboard handling by great amount. It's much more likely for me to implement it poorly than SDL. So I see no reason to try fixing that is not broken (unless you can say what is wroing with my code now).